# disabling alt+shift+print key combination by auto hot key script

Tags: autohotkey

I need a script of AHK for disabling the <kbd>alt+shift+print</kbd> key combination  from the computer.

I have tried below script but the script is not working.

```
!Shift::return
```

Comment: I do not know much about AutoHotKey, but quick readings suggest **!LShift & !RShift:: return** may work, have you tried this? Or what are you attempting to stop? If it is just PrintScreen, maybe just remove the capability of that key

Comment: Showing error invalid hot key.

Comment: By Print, do you mean PrintScreen?

Comment: If they do mean PrintScreen then I am finding you cannot bind those keys via the normal syntax. I am also getting an Invalid Hotkey error on this code: `+!PrintScreen::return`. But if you are only trying to disable high contrast hotkeys then there looks to be a windows setting for this. https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-high-contrast-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-10.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i want to do the same with the programming.

Answer (score 0):

Windows catches the shortcut on a lower level than Autohotkey so first you need to disable High Contrast Keyboard Shortcut 
(see
[Disable High Contrast Keyboard Shortcut in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-high-contrast-keyboard-shortcut-windows-10/)).

Then this will work: `+!PrintScreen::return`